# switch images using javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to switch these pictures by clicking.  The javascript came straight from mozilla tutorial, so I am not sure why it does not work, nothing happens at all.  I am developing in cloud9.

My HTML:

```
<img id="swagBunny" src="images/large.jpg" height="150" width="186" alt="Swaggy Bunny"/>
```

My Java Script:

```
var myImage = document.querySelector('img');

$(function(){ 
   myImage.onclick = function() {
        var mySrc = myImage.getAttribute('src');
        if(mySrc === 'images/large.jpg') {
            myImage.setAttribute ('src','images/images.jpg');
         } else {
            myImage.setAttribute ('src','images/large.jpg');
         }
   };
});
```

Comment: Your supposed HTML is also JavaScript! Please provide the corresponding HTML instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't see why it's not working. Here's a working example with your JavaScript:

```js
$(function(){ 
   var myImage = document.querySelector('img');
   myImage.onclick = function() {
        var mySrc = myImage.getAttribute('src');
        if(mySrc === 'http://static.tumblr.com/1bd1b615e6da70dd71dc84fd2f47c80d/zpmncfu/oxNng9hfv/tumblr_static_95p88l86si88ks4w4wws04wk8.png') {
            myImage.setAttribute ('src','https://cdn-insomniac.s3.amazonaws.com/emoji_sexface.png');
         } else {
            myImage.setAttribute ('src','http://static.tumblr.com/1bd1b615e6da70dd71dc84fd2f47c80d/zpmncfu/oxNng9hfv/tumblr_static_95p88l86si88ks4w4wws04wk8.png');
         }
   };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://static.tumblr.com/1bd1b615e6da70dd71dc84fd2f47c80d/zpmncfu/oxNng9hfv/tumblr_static_95p88l86si88ks4w4wws04wk8.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

Comment: Is it because my variable myImage is defined outside of the function?

Comment: I don't think that's a problem. What error do you see in the console? And did you include the jQuery?

Comment: I believe it was just a glitch with Cloud9 because it works perfectly now, thanks for the help